# Error using the User Defined function of Excel in Matlab

Tags: matlab, excel, excel-formula, vba

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Excel Addin Error #NAME?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352577/excel-addin-error-name)

I think it is a follow-up query to my earlier reported issue concerning User defined function in Excel.

I am able to use the function in Excel when used Manually, but when I write to an excel file using Matlab using xlswrite, it gives an error `#NAME?`

[image: Using the function manually]

I am attaching the screenshots of the both when entered manually and when using the function through Matlab.

[image: Using xlswrite in Matlab]

Thanks

EDIT :

Thanks a lot. I have stored the VBA function as an Excel addin here :

C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Addins

Here is what I saw about Excel Add-ins not loaded when used in Automation :

http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming/472145-calling-excel-macro-from-vb-6-app-problem.html

I am attaching the small snippet of the code from chi_squared() here :

```
Function Chi_Squared(act, exp, Optional df)
```

This is how I write to an excel file in Matlab :

Formula_chisqr={[ '=chi_squared(' 'O2:O22'  ',' 'M2:22' ')']};

[status, message] = xlswrite1(ExcelFilename,Formula_chisqr,sheetname, Location_Agg);

I also tried giving the complete path as suggested. But it did not work.

Thanks

Comment: Just saw your previous question after answering this one. If it's still does not work for you, please give more details: How your function defined (show the first line)? In which file? Where the file stored? In which file you call the function (both manually and from matlab)?

Comment: @Yuk, Thank you so much, I just edited the question. Please let me know if you need any additional information.

Comment: Try to define your function as `Public Function ...`

Comment: I am really sorry,  it did not work either :(

Comment: Does it work if you open a new file in Excel, enter some data and call the function? If yes, it's very strange that it doesn't work from MATLAB. After you call `xlswrite`, open the saved file and try to recalculate the sheet. Will it change anything?

Comment: Yes, It works with the new Excel sheet. But it does not work when I use xlswrite. I noticed that, the add-in ( VBA function) is not loaded when I call the function from Matlab. However it would be loaded when I create a new file in Excel. Let me try the recalculate step you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the workbook where the UDF defined. Even if your function is it your PERSONAL.XLSB file. You don't have to do it only if UDF is defined in the same file where you use it.

For example,

```
='myFunctions.xlsb'!chi_squired(O2:O21,P2:P21)
```

If `myFunctions.xlsb` is not opened you may need to specify full path to the file.

If you want to be able to call UDF in any file without specifying the file name, you need to save the file as Add-in, and then enable it in `Options - Add-ins - Manage Add-ins`.

---

Another idea: When you use XLSWRITE provide file name with extension XLSX, like `test.xlsx`, not just `test`. By default MATLAB saves files with `XLS` extention in older format. It looks like when you open such file in newer version of Excel (2007/2010) the compatibility mode does not allow macros or UDFs to run.

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for your answer and your time in helping. unfortunately, it didn't work. I found a solution. I am posting here so that I might help other SO forum users. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you open the Excel as a COM server, the UDF's and Add-ins are not loaded by default. So, you need to first load the add-ins if you would like to use the add-in your Excel file.

Here is the small code snippet in Matlab which loads the add-ins before opening the Excel file.

```
Excel = actxserver ('Excel.Application'); 
Excel.Workbooks.Open('C:\YourAddInFolder\AddInNameWithExtension'); 
Excel.Workbooks.Item('AddInNameWithExtension').RunAutoMacros(1); 

File='C:\YourFileFolder\FileName'; 
if ~exist(File,'file') 
    ExcelWorkbook = Excel.Workbooks.Add; 
    ExcelWorkbook.SaveAs(File,1); 
    ExcelWorkbook.Close(false); 

end 
Excel.Workbooks.Open(File);
```

Source :  [Mathworks](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22365-function-for-faster-data-transfer-matlab-%3C-%3E-excel)

Comment: Hi @Kiran. If this is the solution to your question, then please check this answer as Accepted (even if you answered yourself). http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions